# hibernate association that does not relate to ID but to one property of Entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to create an association between two entities Parent and Child with the constraint that Child ID correspond to a non unique property of Parent. Is it possible with Hibernate or shall I cope this without Hibernate ?

Here is Parent entity

```
public class Parent {

   @column("parent_id")
   private Integer parent_id

   @column("identifiant")
   private Integer identifiant

   @column("version")
   private Integer version

With a UNIQUE constraint on (identifiant, version)
```

and here is the Child Entity

```
public class Child{

   @column("identifiant")
   private Integer identifiant

   @column("document1")
   private byte[] document1

   @column("document2")
   private byte[] document2

with identifiant as primary key and also as foreign key on (Parent, identifiant)
```

Is it possible to manage this association with Hibernate and if so how, or shall I manage this association without hibernate and manage the Child Entity as a independant Entity ?

### UPDATE

I found another issue. When I add a constraint of foreign key on (PARENT_TABLE, identifiant) like the following :

```
ALTER table PARENT_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT cts_1 FOREIGN KEY (identifiant) REFERENCES CHILD_TABLE(identifiant);
```

it complaints that there are non existent row in CHILD_TABLE

Comment: Sounds just like a foreign key constraint.

Comment: Yes but the foreign key does not relate on the Parent ID. is it still possible to build a @OneToOne Association based on identifiant foreign key ?

Comment: Why not try it out?

Comment: I will try and let you know at the beginning of the afternoon

Comment: Hello see UPDATE. I have a new issue

Comment: That's a SQL issue...

Comment: Yes, I can insert data in CHILD_TABLE for existing identifiant in PARENT_TABLE, but does it mean that I have to create a Child entity before creating a Parent entity in Java ?

Comment: That depends on how you set up the constraint. If the constaint is on the `PARENT_TABLE` (which it seems to be) then yes, you have to create the row in `CHILD_TABLE` before the row in `PARENT_TABLE` can reference it.

Comment: I implemented the whole and it works. I used a @ManyToOne association. Thanks a lot